# NameError: name 'sacc_dictionary' is not defined

Tags: dictionary, prediction, tracking, eye-tracking, amplitude

actually i am developping an eye movement application, i create dictionary for saccade-based n-grams:
where each character encodes one direction, capital characters stand for long saccades, the      others for short ones and short means the saccade amplitude is less than 2 fixation_radius_thresholds.

`sacc_dictionary = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'R', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'D', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'U', 'u', 'b', 'r', 'f', 'd', 'j', 'l', 'n'] sacc_bins_two = [a+b for a in sacc_dictionary for b in sacc_dictionary] sacc_bins_three = [a+b+c for a in sacc_dictionary for b in sacc_dictionary for c in sacc_dictionary] sacc_bins_four = [a+b+c+d for a in sacc_dictionary for b in sacc_dictionary for c in sacc_dictionary for d in sacc_dictionary] sacc_bins = [sacc_dictionary, sacc_bins_two, sacc_bins_three, sacc_bins_four]`

i'm getting this error:
sacc_bins_two = {a+b for a in sacc_dictionary for b in sacc_dictionary}
NameError: name 'sacc_dictionary' is not defined

can anyone help me
thankyou

i tried to search the solution but i didnt get it.